# Silex 2 - How to mouth dynamic routes ? As in version 1 of Silex

Tags: php, symfony, routes, silex

I have a project that use Silex 1.2 in addition to updating to version 2. But mounting routes dynamically in a controller no longer works. My new routes are not saved.

```
// routing.php
$app->get('/', 'App\\Controllers\\App::main')->bind('app_main');

// App.php
class App {
    function main(Application $app, Request $request) {
        $name = 'basic';
        $version = 1;

        $moduleClass = 'App\Core\Modules\\'.$name.'\v'.$version.'\\ControllerProvider';
        $app->mount($request->getPathInfo(), new $moduleClass($name, $version));

        $subRequest = Request::create(
            $app['url_generator']->generate('basic_1'),
            'POST'
        );

        return $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST, false);
    }
}
```

And my application can not find the new route, this code work with Silex 1.2... I can not find what has changed in version 2.

Comment: Your class names is `Routing` shouldn't be the route controller as  `App\\Controllers\\Routing::main`?

Comment: Yep, sorry it's error on my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `flush` the controller collection. After you `mount` them, call this:

```
$app->flush();
```